# How to transport the Spotlight API code to the view controller

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, spotlight

I have written my Spotlight API code and it seems to be working okay. I can check it out in the spotlight but there's only one problem :

It won't take me to the desired view controller! How do I do that? I've added a

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showIt" {

        let ThatVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ItThat


    }
}
```

but it still won't take me to the right spot. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`prepareForSegue` is used to notify the view controller that a segue is about to be performed (what data to prepare, confirms destination, etc). `prepareForSegue` is only called when a segue has already been initiated. It does not however perform the segue itself.

If your segue **is unconditional**, just use a standard segue in Interface Builder (pull from the `UIButton` to your destination scene).

If your segue **is conditional**, pull from the `UIButton`'s parent scene to the destination scene in Interface Builder. Once this is finished, you can create a new `@IBAction` and perform a segue manually.

```
 @IBAction func fooAction() {
      performSegueWithIdentifier("showIt", sender: self)
 }
```

Just make sure "showIt" is the segue's identifier.

[image]

Comment: That's what I have. I get a SIGABRT error when I run it.

Comment: Remove your `prepareForSegue`. It's not doing anything. Make sure you've connected the segues/identifiers/ `@IBActions` up correctly.

Comment: They're setup. The SIGABRT disappears when the prepareForSegue is gone, but it's also removing the purpose I need it for. When I search for whatever in spotlight, and press it, it should take me to my view controller.